# React Query - SetQueryCache must follow with a refetch?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using react query with nextJS. I set the stale time to 10 minutes so while I'm using the app I don't refetch without reason.

Now when i update data in my react query I set the data value in the query cache (SetQueryCache) - that does not invalidate the query (Say I have a list of tasks and i set one of them to done).

Now after i updated the data (Set a task to done) i refresh the page but i see the old data, only when i invalidate the query manually it fetches the correct date.

I am having the same issue with Delete but not with create.(Create gets updated and holds in refresh)

I thought using setQueryCache with the updated data let's react query know that it was changed but the data is not updated, how can i solve this?

I don't want to fetch data on the client side every time i update the queryCache.
I would appriciate any help :)

SetQuery Cache -> updates the query cache does not need refetch.
Actually does need

Comment: Please provide a code sample of your mutation and `setQueryData()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.